# Is the "store" compression level always faster than the rest?

Tags: 7-zip

I have an encrypted 7z video archive and performing any change takes several minutes to process. When selecting "store" compression level the program sets "memory usage for compressing"/..."decompressing" to 1 MB and doesn't allow changing "number of CPU threads" from 1:

[image: settings]

Can using compression be faster over not using it at all (because the video codecs are efficient compression won't save any space)?

Comment: Short answer: no. The reason that updates are slow is simply due to the need to expand the whole archive, then update and recreate it, all of which is disc-intensive. As you rightly say, you will not save any significant amount of space. On a highly compressible archive you might save time because there will be reduced disc access on the archive itself.

Comment: Relevant reading: https://superuser.com/questions/1095142/advantages-of-the-store-compression-level-in-7zip https://superuser.com/questions/131899/how-to-make-7-zip-faster https://superuser.com/questions/281573/what-are-the-best-options-to-use-when-compressing-files-using-7-zip https://superuser.com/questions/720178/does-7zip-compression-level-affect-decompression-speed

Comment: @music2myear: "What are the best setting to use when compressing a text file to a zip format when my only need is a small file size?"

Comment: What is the reason you're storing in an encrypted 7zip file? Are you just looking for encryption? There are better solutions a 7zip store designed for encrypted storage of in-use files. Right now, all of the components of your current question are answered in the various questions I've linked. If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, that would set your question apart as being unique and would allow us to give you the best answer, not just a correct answer.

Comment: @music2myear: I only need encryption. I will go through all of your links now.

Comment: This one: https://superuser.com/a/720195/74026

Comment: @music2myear: My title still stands, I'm asking if "store" setting is the fastest or not and gave some additional information.

Comment: @music2myear: Both Windows (10) and Linux. I assumed that the question is platform-agnostic. Add if you consider this information necessary.

Comment: @music2myear: The question has been answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/720178/does-7zip-compression-level-affect-decompression-speed/). I will accept your closure flag if it can be changed.'